# Why there is an increase in reported issues after SonarQube version upgrade?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I updated sonarqube from 4.4 to 4.5.4LTS.

After initial analysis on a project using the same set of rules as in my previous version, number of issues increased by a significant
 number.

Build breaker broke my build gracefully as the number of critical issues shot past my quality gate thresholds.

I double checked the number of rules on the previous instance. Its exactly the same.

Comment: Would you be able to precise which rules raised more issues ? and moreover on which language ? If I guess correctly I would say it was on java, would you be able to tell us the version of the sonar java plugin in your 4.4 instance and in your 4.5.4 ?

Comment: Only java rules. i have **v2.2.1** default java and findbugs plugin on v4.4 and **v2.4** default java and findbugs plugin on v4.5.4 of sonarqube.
I might need some time to find the exact rules that raised issues. Will check it and get back.
But what keeps me wondering is that the number of rules shown is the same on both versions.

Comment: Rules might have been improved between those two java plugin version which might explain why, while not changing the quality profile, you have more issues.

Comment: I would also recommend you to use latest versions of the sonar-java plugin (version 3.4 at time of writing)

Comment: Updated to v3.4, still the same. 
Yes, default rule-set have been improved. But since it shows me the same  number of rules as previous, I couldn't answer why there is a huge increase in reported critical issues.

Comment: I am not talking about rule-set (ie: quality profile) but rule themselves have been reworked between version. To shed some light it would be really interesting to know which rule is raising more issue than previously. To know this, you can compare the number of issues raised by rules. Number of rule is also a bit misleading as some rule might have been deactivated by default whereas some new where activated.